# how to probe corruption of, or changing answer from C++ std::filesystem::exists function

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, std

First: I do not know how to create an MVCE of this problem. I realize that is a big no no for this site, but I frankly there is a lot of expertise here and I don't know a better place to ask this question.  Maybe the answer is, post this question `<insert other site here>`.

The question: any thoughts as to what is going on here, and how can I probe this problem?

Anyway, code base is >10K lines of fortran that is also linking in an open source C++ library, `nanort`. So its a combined in house code of Fortran and C++ with a lot going on.

Somewhere in the code I have to read in a binary file in C++ and parse it.  The problem I am running into is that 10% of the time, the function `std::filesystem::exists` is telling me the file does not exist, even though it does.  In fact, the fortran `inquire` routine tells me it does exist in the same execution of the program.  Furthermore, at the beginning of the program, the `std::filesystem::exists` routine tells me it does exist.

So here's that layed out in a simple text diagram

```
program starts

fortran calls C++ -> std::filesystem::exists reports that the file exists

...
many other things happen
...

fortran calls C++ -> std::filesystem::exists reports that the file does not exists and returns to fortran with an error flag

the fortran inquire function reports that the file does in fact exist
```

Remember, this only happens 10% of the time.  The other 90% of the time the program runs fine (as far as I can tell).

System Info:

```
Mac OSX Big Sur
g++11, with -std=c++17 and -O3
gfortran with -fbounds-check and -O3
```

Comment: One thing you could do would be to use the `std::error_code` overload of `std::filesystem::exists` to hopefully be able to capture if there was some sort of IO failure.

Comment: Some useful details: Is the file there all the time, or is it recreated during the program run? Some OS's have a delay before it gets visible again. Do you use a full path or a relative path? Some IDEs may change the "current directory" a bit randomly, when they feel like it.

Comment: Smells like some undefined behavior caused by likes of buffer overflow, usage of dangling references, race condition or similar. Dozen kilos of SLOC is tiny ... and Apple tries to help too a bit ... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early

Comment: @BoP It is always there

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer this one even though it's a little embarrassing.

When passing a fortran character array to a C void function, you pass it as a pointer to a character array.  When doing so, you need to make sure that your character array has a null termination at the point where you want it.

Although I was creating a copy of the filename with a null termination, I was passing the non-null terminated string to C++ by mistake.  Given the undefined bits of the program, most of the time this was actually succeeding anyway, but sometimes it was not and I was getting a non-null terminated string for a filename that the system was telling me did not exist.